# How to reference modules within express routes

Tags: node.js, express

I want to have my express routes in separate files, but I am having a hard time determining what the best practice is for referencing modules in the routes.

Here are the various methods that I have seen below. Which one is the best practice? Does this change at all based on what you are trying to do (logging, configuration, data sources, etc)?

Note these are missing big gaps just to make the post shorter.

1. "Require" within both the app and route.

```
//app.js
var cfg = require('./config.js');

//router.js
var cfg = require('./config.js');

module.exports = function () {

    var router = new express.Router();

    router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
        console.log('cfg', cfg);
    });

    return router;
};
```

2. Pass into the module

```
//app.js
var cfg = require('./config.js');
app.use(require('./router')(cfg));

//router.js
module.exports = function (cfg) {

    var router = new express.Router();

    router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
        console.log('cfg', cfg);
    });

    return router;
};
```

3. Use express app.set/get

```
//app.js
var cfg = require('./config.js');
app.set('cfg', cfg);

//router.js
module.exports = function () {

    var router = new express.Router();

    router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
        console.log('cfg', app.get('cfg'));
    });

    return router;
};
```

4. Use express middleware and add to req

```
//app.js
var cfg = require('./config.js');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.cfg = cfg;
  next();
});

//router.js
module.exports = function () {

    var router = new express.Router();

    router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
        console.log('cfg', req.cfg);
    });

    return router;
};
```

Comment: How about `global.cfg = require('./config.js');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module design in node.js really depends upon your goals for a module.

I generally start out thinking that a module should be as reusable as possible without contorting or complicating the design beyond what is likely to be needed.  Sometimes it takes no extra work to just organize the code in a reusable way.  Sometimes you find that the reusable, general purpose scheme is a lot more work or complication.  If it ends up being a lot more work and the likelihood that you will ever reuse the module is low, then your code might actually be simpler and better if you don't try to make it generically reusable.  So, anyway the main point here is that you have to figure out what the goal is for the module and you can then base your design decisions based on that goal.

---

If the module is designed to be independently usable in other applications, then the module should really be as stand-alone as possible.  That means it should either `require()` in everything it needs (your option 1) or it should clearly document what needs to be passed into the module constructor (your option 2).  That would allow the module to be used in other projects without having to be part of a complicated environment (of globals, app configs, etc...).

A core principle of module reusability is making them as stand-alone as possible and as easy to use as possible.  Whether you require in a config module or pass a configuration object to the constructor really depends upon you envision a situation where you want to caller to be able to manage the config object itself rather than having the module load the config object from its own location.  That is a design decision depending upon your design objectives.

---

If, for whatever reason, the module is not intended to be usable in other applications and you don't really see any benefit in planning for that, then it's perfectly fine to design your module to assume a certain environment that is going to be present in your application.  This could include either your options 3 (app.set/get) or 4 (middleware cfg).  Personally, I would avoid the middleware scheme just because I try to avoid adding work that applies to every request, when only some routes might need that info.  The work here isn't much, but conceptually, I don't like making the `req` object be the union of everything that every possible request handler might need.  And I'd prefer the code being more specific where a route uses `app.get()` to get the config when needed.  But, either could work fine.

---

P.S. I would not use the `global.cfg` suggestion from a comment.  This is immediately incompatible with any other module that also decides to use `global.cfg` for its own purposes which is exactly why we avoid globals.

`app.get/set` are similar to globals, but if you own the `app` object, then you control its namespace and you shouldn't find random other modules that are using that same namespace so it's a better situation than actual globals.  And, in fact, no other code can use that unless you first gave them the `app` object anyway (which is why they aren't actually globals).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say "it depends" on what exactly you're looking to pass into the route.

1. I would use this approach for utility or global modules (e.g. lodash or similar, or a module providing application configurations). This allows the routes to only require the module, if it is actually used in this route.
2. I would use this approach for certain objects that are created at the application level and you need to ensure that the same instance is used across the application (e.g. a database connection provider object or similar). This affects the signature of the function that you have to export in your route file as you add more objects, so you would probably want to keep this list relatively short and make sure that these objects are used by all or at least most routes.
3. I have actually never used this myself, but it looks like this should be used for setting configuration related to express.
4. I would use this approach to set properties that are related to one specific request (e.g. if you have an authentication middleware, you could set the currently logged in user onto the request like this, so that following middlewares can access it). This adds a middleware that is executed for every single request, which can add some unnecessary overhead once the application grows and you have more and more objects that you would want to pass into the routes.